# I need my method to return two Maps. Is this possible?

Tags: apex, trigger, map

How would I go about returning two Maps from a method? If it is not possible, could you offer a work-around?

I would like my Method to return:

```
Map(Lead, Set<Date>)
Map(Lead, Set<String>)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apex does not allow multiple return types. However, you can create a custom type to be returned from your method. It would have a `Lead` and a `Set<Date>` and a `Set<String>` in it - allowing you to have strings and dates per Lead.

Similar to this:

```
public class LeadWrapperThing {
    public Lead theLead             { get; set; }
    public Set<String> theStrings   { get; set; }
    public Set<Date> theDates       { get; set; }
}

public List<LeadWrapperThing> getLeadWrapperThings() {

    List<LeadWrapperThing> thingsList = new List<LeadWrapperThing>();

    for (Lead someLead : listOfLeads) {

        // create the wrapper
        LeadWrapperThing lThing = new LeadWrapperThing();

        // stick the lead in the wrapper
        lThing.theLead = someLead;

        // add stuff to the string set
        lThing.theStrings = new Set<String>();
        lThing.theStrings.add('a value');

        // add stuff to the date set
        lThing.theDates = new Set<Date>();
        lThing.theDates.add(Date.today());

        // add the wrapper object into the list to be returned
        thingsList.add(lThing);
    }

    return thingsList;
}
```

or as an answer to your comment, if you want to use the lead as the key also and return a map

```
public Map<Lead, LeadWrapperThing> getLeadWrapperThingsMap() {

    Map<Lead, LeadWrapperThing> thingsMap = new Map<Lead, LeadWrapperThing>();

    for (Lead someLead : listOfLeads) {

        // create the wrapper
        LeadWrapperThing lThing = new LeadWrapperThing();

        // stick the lead in the wrapper
        lThing.theLead = someLead;

        // add stuff to the string set
        lThing.theStrings = new Set<String>();
        lThing.theStrings.add('a value');

        // add stuff to the date set
        lThing.theDates = new Set<Date>();
        lThing.theDates.add(Date.today());

        // add the wrapper object into the Map to be returned, using the lead as the key
        thingsMap.put(someLead, lThing);
    }

    return thingsMap;
}

// Usage:
// Map<Lead, LeadWrapperThing> wrappedLeadMap = yourClass.getLeadWrapperThingsMap();
// LeadWrapperThing wrappedThingForThisLead = wrappedLeadMap.get(theLead);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was hoping to return multiple maps because I want the ability to search via keys. Is it possible to "search" the returned "thingsList" using key-value pairs as you would a map? Is there a different way to do this while using wrapper classes?

Comment: What is it that you want to search by? Lead?

Comment: Yes, search by lead

Comment: Updated the answer to provide a Map return.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, by searching the key Lead, the map will return a leadWrapperThing object. From there you can use dot notation to access the leadWrapperThing's variables?

Comment: Yes indeed. You are correct.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to creating a new class to hold the values as Mark Pond suggested, you could take advantage of the fact that `Maps`, like all collection types, are reference types rather than value types, and simply provide variables for the method to fill as parameters.

```
void fillLeadStringDates(Map<Lead, Set<String>> stringset, Map<Lead, Set<Date>> dateset)
{   
    stringset.put(aNewLead, 'a string');
    dateset.put(aNewLead, Date.newInstance(0, 0, 0));
}
```